# count amount of days user enter into db

Tags: mysql

I have a table of items similar to this:

```
id | desc | created    | user
-----------------------------
1  | a... | 2015-05-23 | 1
2  | b... | 2015-05-23 | 1
3  | c... | 2015-06-23 | 1
4  | d... | 2015-07-23 | 2
5  | e... | 2015-07-23 | 1
```

I want to count the amount of days where the user submitted to the db. MY desired result from the above example would be:
User 1: 3
User 2: 1

Comment: `user, count(*) .. group by user`

Comment: @Vishal Zanzrukia sorry but this only gives me the total amount of id's... i am looking to get the amount of days! As you can see above user 1 entered rows on three different dates, so my count should result in 3...

Comment: if you want the distinct number of days they have clocked in then see Vishals answer below

Comment: @Vishal Zanzrukia: am sorry to say but thats not what am looking for. Please read my question! How can that gives me a single result with the amount of days?

Comment: did you try it? It will give you the results, please check sqlfiddle demo.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Please try below query, I hope it helps.

```sql
select user, count(distinct date(created)) from table_name group by user;
```

[**SQLFiddle**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/2166f/2)

Answer (score 0):

```
select user,count(DISTINCT created) from tableName group by user;
```

[Here](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/group-by-functions.html#function_count-distinct) is an explanation how `COUNT(DISTINCT  )` works.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT created) from items WHERE user=':user_id'
```

This is assuming your 'created' column only receives distinct daily values, if not, you would have to use trim functions.